# Why does laravel need authentication while sending mails?

Tags: laravel, email, authentication

Why does laravel need authentication while sending mails? Is it possible to send mail without authentication just a valid email id?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what is an email id?

Comment: What error are you getting? Laravel doesn't require a user to send an email so my guess is you're probably seeing some kind of error due to bad credentials for your outgoing mail server. If you're able to give a bit more information it would help a ton.

Comment: Of course, you can do it. Authentication is not required to send email in Laravel.

Comment: Show us the codes for sending email and route you are using to reach there. May be your route is gaurd with auth so the authentication is required.

Comment: I meant the username and password in the .env file. Without those credentials the mail is not going.